# C# Class using double Generics: give only one when both of them should be the same?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

So I'm struggling a bit with a certain piece of code, and I'm not sure if there's a better way to handle it - but it feels like it's possible.

Let's say I have a class:

```
public class DeviceProcessingResult<TSucceeded, TFailed>
    {
        public TSucceeded[] Succeeded { get; set; }

        public TFailed[] Failed { get; set; }

        public DeviceProcessingResult(IEnumerable<TSucceeded> succeeded, IEnumerable<TFailed> failed)
        {
            Succeeded = succeeded.Cast<TSucceeded>().ToArray();
            Failed = failed.Cast<TFailed>().ToArray();
        }
    }
```

I use this class to create objects that contain an Array of object that have succeeded in their processing, and an Array of objects that have failed. This type of object gets used on various parts of the code we currently have. In one of those places, we would use it like this:

```
return new DeviceProcessingResult<DeviceResponse, DeviceModel>(succeeded, failed);
```

Since we need to return the results, and the type of object that gets returned when processing has succeeded contains other/more info than the model that gets returned when processing has failed.

Now this is currently the only piece of code that has 2 different types of objects, as all other code looks like this:

```
return new DeviceProcessingResult<DeviceModel, DeviceModel>(succeeded, failed);
```

So as you see, we use 2 times the same object.

The point of this question now is: Is it possible to do something like

```
return new DeviceProcessingResult<DeviceModel>(succeeded, failed);
```

Since it's gonna be the same things there anyways? Or is there no (good) way around this and should we always specify both types?

Comment: I believe you can just call it like `return new DeviceProcessingResult(succeeded, failed);` and the type will get inferred from the passed in arguments type

Comment: Why do you need the `.Cast<TSucceeded>()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy solution would be to simply inherit this class like this:

```
public class DeviceProcessingResult<T> : DeviceProcessingResult<T, T>
{
    public DeviceProcessingResult(IEnumerable<T> succeeded, IEnumerable<T> failed)
        : base(succeeded, failed)
    { /*Nothing more to do here...*/ }
}

public class DeviceProcessingResult<T, T1>
{
    public T[] Succeeded { get; set; }
    public T1[] Failed { get; set; }

    public DeviceProcessingResult(IEnumerable<T> succeeded, IEnumerable<T1> failed)
    {
        Succeeded = succeeded.ToArray();
        Failed = failed.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I don't really understand why you think my answer should also contain a copy (with a slight improvement) of the code in the question.

Comment: 'cause for newbies it wasn't that clear, this way, they can understand what you did, better

Comment: Thank you for this answer! This is most likely the way to go, I was already thinking that it had to be something in that line...

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Ok, I thought it might be something like this.

Comment: @otomo if an answer solved your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

To do this you would need to have another intermediate class, for example:

```
public class public class DeviceProcessingResult<TDeviceModel> 
    : DeviceProcessingResult<TDeviceModel, TDeviceModel>
{
}
```

Alternatively, you can rely on the compiler inferring the types based on the parameters:

```
return new DeviceProcessingResult(succeeded, failed)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
    public class DeviceProcessingResult<TFailed> : DeviceProcessingResult< DeviceResponse, TFailed>
    {
        public DeviceProcessingResult(IEnumerable<DeviceResponse> succeeded, IEnumerable<TFailed> failed) : base(succeeded, failed)
        {
        }
    }
```